# How to use google calendar in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone application.i wanted to implement the google calendar in my application, i don't have any kind of idea about this so please give me some example and idea about google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Calendar API page you can find some useful links: [Client libraries for google services](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/code.html), [ObjC library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction), [sample Calendar project](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/)